# ZEBRA Printer sometimes prints an empty page

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, cups

I have a **ZEBRA ZT230 ZPL Labelprinter** configured under **Linux Debian** and under **Linux Ubuntu**. Since there are no official drivers (for anything but Windows) I am **using the CUPS Driver for Linux**. Most of the time the printer works fine but statistically speaking 1/5 Jobs **prints an empty page instead** of the page to print. I am printing the same page and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't (seems to be totally random).

I am quite sure that the problem lies in the driver, because with the official driver **on a Windows system I get 100% success rate** printing anyhthing.

I probably tried all possible settings under "Modify Printer" and "Set Default Options" and played with different label sizes. I tried to print different media types like a webpage from Firefox, PDF or Textfile. But everytime I get the same random behaviour.

Anyone had the same experience using the CUPS Driver or a ZEBRA label printer? Any ideas on how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zebra printer can print PDF, Word and lot of document.s But it's not the way it must work. From windows I always use a driver called "Generic Driver / Text Only" with my Zebra and send pure ZPL code.
Learn how to code with ZPL by downloading the official ZPL guide: https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf
Practice with a ZPL software like https://www.zpldesigner.com

It will work at 100%

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will check it out.

In my case I want a non programmer to be able to design a html page. My program will convert the html page to a pdf, which shall be printed. Before reading into your links I have the feeling, that I might not get this kind of freedom.

My problem in general is that the official windows driver prints anything 100% of a time. So my idea was to achieve this behaviour in Linux.

Comment: Thanks again for ur solution. I ended up converting my html to bitmap and putting that into ZPL. Works perfectly now!

Comment: Perfect, glad I could help!